# Automate Gatling Tests scenarios

Tags: testing, performance-testing, gatling, stress-testing

I have a Druid Setup in Kubernetes. To test the performance of queries, I created a local Gatling setup and configured queries to test the load and stress of the system.
But we are still in the process of evaluating and tuning Druid. So we need to run these tests every time we make a config change, to ensure that the property really helps and for documentation purposes.

```
val httpConf = http.baseUrl("http://localhost:8082/druid/")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .proxy(Proxy("localhost", 8082))

 val scn = scenario("Druid_Feldspar_Query_Perf_Test_approx_distinct_without_filter")
   .exec(http("complex_join_round_filter")
   .post("v2/sql").body(RawFileBody("count_query")))

setUp(
    scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(50) during(60.second))
  ).protocols(httpConf)
```

Right now all the Gatling steps are manual, as shown above. I get an HTML file after each run that I parse to get the numbers.
Has anybody done something that can automate this process? Can we deploy in Kubernetes?

Any help or pointers are helpful? Please let me know if any further inputs are needed.

Answer (score 0):

The official solution is [FrontLine](https://gatling.io/gatling-frontline/). Amongst other solutions, it can deploy your injectors in k8s.